# Combine multiple javascript forms into one single form with select options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a JavaScript-based offline android app using Phonegap. In the `index.html` are four forms for searching in the database:

```
<form onsubmit="s1(); return false;">
  <input id="search1" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Search in Titles only" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<form onsubmit="s2(); return false;">
  <input id="search2" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Search in Titles + Contents" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<form onsubmit="scat(); return false;">
  <input id="cat" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Search in Categories" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<form onsubmit="gotoid(); return false;">
  <input id="articleid" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Find based on ID" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

And the following is the in-page script:

```
function s1() {
  window.location.href = "search1.html?" + document.getElementById("search1").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, "+");
}

function s2() {
  window.location.href = "search2.html?" + document.getElementById("search2").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, "+");
}

function scat() {
  window.location.href = "cat.html?" + document.getElementById("cat").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, "+");
}

function gotoid() {
  window.location.href = "id.html#" + document.getElementById("articleid").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, "");
}
```

The problem is the page is quite dirty. I tried to combine these four forms into one, maintaining their functions by adding `<select>` and `<options>`, but I couldn't get it working.

Any suggestion, whether `CSS`, `HTML`, `JavaScript`, or their combinations (but not jQuery) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="button"]' );

btns.forEach( function( item, index) {
    item.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        var elm = item.previousElementSibling,
            eid = ( index !=3 ) ? elm.id + '.html?' : 'id.html#',
            val = elm.value.trim().replace( /\s+/g, '+' );

        /* window.location.href = eid + '.html?' + val */
        console.log( eid + val )
    } )
} )
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="search1" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Search in Titles only" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" /><br />
  <input id="search2" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Search in Titles + Contents" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" /><br />
  <input id="cat" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Search in Categories" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" /><br />
  <input id="articleid" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Find based on ID" value="" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" /><br />
</form>
```

**About your updated code:**

This solution is better. But you can simply do this as below:

```js
function search() {
    var select = document.getElementById( 'select' ),
        value = document.getElementById( 'key' ).value.trim().replace( /\s+/g,'+' );

    /*window.location.href = select.options[ select.selectedIndex ].value + value;*/
    console.log( select.options[ select.selectedIndex ].value + value )
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="search(); return false;">
  <input id="key" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="" value="" />
  <select id="select">
    <option value="search1.html?" selected>Only in Titles</option>
    <option value="search2.html?">In Titles + Contents</option>
    <option value="cat.html?">In Categories</option>
    <option value="id.html#">Based on ID</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: I've just managed to get it working. Please have a look and let me know if it is a standard way. Thanks

Comment: Your HTML is better than the original HTML, but it might be confusing, considering four inputs and four buttons. Anyway, I voted for it.

Comment: @Siamak, You are right. But I only updated her code. Thanks for your vote.

Comment: Kavian, the updated code is fine. The shorter, the better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. Here is the new HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="search(); return false;">
<input id="key" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="" value="" />
<select>
<option id="s1" selected>Only in Titles</option>
<option id="s2">In Titles + Contents</option>
<option id="scat">In Categories</option>
<option id="gotoid">Based on ID</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

And the new script is the following:

```
function search(){
if(document.getElementById("s1").selected == true){
window.location.href = "search1.html?" + document.getElementById("key").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g,"+");
}

else if(document.getElementById("s2").selected == true){
window.location.href = "search2.html?" + document.getElementById("key").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g,"+");
}

else if(document.getElementById("scat").selected == true){
window.location.href = "cat.html?" + document.getElementById("key").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g,"+");
}

else if(document.getElementById("gotoid").selected == true){
window.location.href = "id.html#" + document.getElementById("key").value.trim().replace(/\s+/g,"");
}

else{
alert('Something went wrong. Please try again!');
}
}
```

Please comment if it is not a standard way to do so.